# I got two translations from two different translators, which is correct?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

I asked two translators for a translation of "The Deep Jungle Rally", in this case, a rally (car race) deep in the jungle, as a proper title.

- **Translator 1**: "El Rallye de la Jungla Profunda"
- **Translator 2**: "El Rallye de Selva Profunda"

I tried to look these up with my limited resources but couldn't really find any solid information on the differences, and I'm left with a few questions:"

1. Which is correct for the given context?
2. When should "jungla" be used vs "selva" if they both mean "jungle"?
3. What is the nuance of using "de la" (of the) instead of "de" (possessive) in the title?
4. Is there anything else I should know when finalizing this translation?

Can anyone help me figure out which title to use?

Comment: As you imply, the difference between [selva](https://dle.rae.es/selva) and [jungla](https://dle.rae.es/jungla) is subtle.  Both can work here: jungla means uncultivated land in the tropics dense with vegetation and selva means a vast uncultivated area with lots of trees.  You can have either "la jungla amazónica" or "la selva amazónica" for the Amazon rainforest but only "la Selva Negra" for the Black Forest.

Comment: Who is running races in the jungle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these are correct. The correct one would be "El rally  de la jungla/selva profunda".

Rallye does not exist in Spanish official dictionary, the correct is "rally".

The nuance of using "de la" is important here. "De" implies possession, so "el rally de Selva Profunda" would only make sense if "Selva Profunda" is a place that "hold" the rallye. For instance, the rallye of Montenegro would be "El rally de Montenegro".